# How to bind more then one property in JavaFx?

Tags: binding, properties, javafx

I'm new to properties and bindings.

If I want to bind one property to another one everything is fine.
But what if I want it to bind to more than one?

To be more specific:
I have 4 sliders. The added value of the first three should be the value of the fourth.

```
slider4.valueProperty().bind(slider1.valueProperty());
slider4.valueProperty().bind(slider2.valueProperty());
slider4.valueProperty().bind(slider3.valueProperty());
```

didn't work. Okay, I did expect that.

What's the way in this case?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`add(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/DoubleExpression.html#add-javafx.beans.value.ObservableNumberValue-) method inherited from `DoubleExpression`:

```
slider4.valueProperty().bind(
    slider1.valueProperty()
    .add(slider2.valueProperty())
    .add(slider3.valueProperty())
);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was easier than I thought.